# Possible to use output data variable from Iterator in SQL query?

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, sql

I am looking to use a value returned by an iterator as part of an SQL query but cannot figure out the right way to do this with an SQL expression:

I have a table of 7 text values *(Cadastre)* that the **'Iterate Field Values"** will run through to generate a table for each of those values where the value from the iterator is used as the new tables name.

I am then looking to structure an SQL expression where I use the value *(Value)* from the iterator to select only rows where a field has the same text value as the value returned from the iterator previously.

I could do what I'm looking to through **"Table to Table"** without the **"Table Select"** as well I suppose if I can figure out the right query.

[image: Model Screenshot]

Comment: `ENG_NAME = '%Value%'`. It's called inline substitution and you can read about it in the help file.

Comment: Thanks, see I have used this before but I thought that it would search for the specific text "Value" in cell contents regardless of what other characters surround it not the value that is returned by by a variable.

Comment: Trying this method it works the first time the iterator runs but when the value changes despite me being able to see that it changes the Table to Table tool that runs after isn't having the value updated for the name of the generated table or the query of what field value to pull

Comment: You need to use the inline variable substitution in the SQL expression to select the rows of interest AND in the output table name to give the output table a unique name. Your current logic keeps overwriting the table.

Comment: For the **Table to Table** tool the "Output Name" field allows me to select the "Value" as a model variable from a dropdown which should do the same thing as the inline variable substitution, no?

Also to be clear when the iterator runs the 2nd, 3rd, etc time despite me seeing the value being updated neither the table name nor the fields that are being pulled by the query change. It only is using the first text value from the iterator for some reason.

Comment: Do you have a selection on the input to the iterator, if so that needs to be cleared.